# Why is a value in a C# Linked List changing when I create a new object?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linked-list

The object I'm using has two values, an object number and a name string;
The object has a constructor that automatically increments the value whenever a new object is created so each object has a unique number.

```
public class MyObject
{
    private static int _objectnumber;
    private string _name; 

     public MyObject()
     {
         ++_objectNumber;
     }
}
```

I create a new object and assign it to a variable.

```
curObject = new MyObject();
```

After getting the name from the user, I insert it into a linked list.

```
if(myLinkedList == null)
{
    myLinkedList = new LinkedList<MyObject>();
    myLinkedList.AddFirst(curObject);
 }
else
{
    // code here to check to make sure the objectnumber is unique

     myLinkedList.AddLast(curObject);         
 }
curObject = null;    //I'm done with this
```

The problem happens when I create a second new object. when I call...

```
 curObject = new MyObject();
```

...for the second time.  The constructor increments the object number, as it should, but it also increments the object number in the first node of the linked list.

It's as if curObject was still pointing to the first node in the list (which is why I set it to null after it was placed in the list.

Originally, the name field in the linked list would also change, but that was fixed by setting curObject to null.

Obviously, when I insert curObject into the linked list, the linked list node just points to the memory where curObject is stored.  However, when I create a new curObject, it seems it simply sets the new object to the same memory space - hence, it points to the first node of the linked list as well.

Comment: There is only one `_objectnumber` I see declared.  There's not one per instance.  It's static, so there's only one per entire process.

Comment: Linked Lists seems to be entirely a red herring in this question. You'd be seeing exactly the same behaviour if you just had two variables containing two instances. And you'd see practically the same issues if you implemented that in [tag:c] also.

Comment: Yeah, Linked Lists was an entire red herring.  I changed to Lists and got the same behavior.  The problem was that I declared the variable as a static. 
Coding while designing and tripping up on early implementation that didn't quite track with the original idea.  <--- Not a good practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Damien commented, your problem has nothing to do with the linked list.

You have defined `_objectnumber` as static to the class, i.e there only one copy for all instances of the class.

Instead, create a private member and assign from the static variable:

```
public class MyObject
{
    private static int Objectnumber = 0;

    private int _objectnumber;
    private string _name; 

    public MyObject()
    {
        _objectNumber = ++Objectnumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all.  That was the problem.  An initial implementation idea that proved not to work as anticipated.